# PHP Google Analytics Data API V1 (Beta) (GA4) Authorization via Service Account

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

My main question is how to get Authorization working in PHP using Google Analytics Data API V1 (Beta)? I have been banging my head against the wall awhile now, receiving this error: "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED" with meta info: "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."

I'm working on a WordPress Plugin that charts Google Analytics GA4 Property Data to a Google Charts Area Chart. Currently Having issues getting initial Authorization to go through Google Analytics Data API. I've followed the documentation, enabled the api, setup the service account, downloaded the JSON key file, added service account to various accounts & properties, etc...

[Google Analytics Data API V1 (Beta) Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)

Documentation for the PHP is a bit lacking for me... but, I'm new. I've tried two ways to auth.

```
// Set the application credentials
$json_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'client_secrets.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $json_path); 

// Initialize the Google Analytics client.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
```

and

```
// Load the service account JSON file for authentication.
$credentials = json_decode( file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json' ), true );

// Initialize the Google Analytics client.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient( [ 'credentials' => $credentials ] );
```

However both produce an error: "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED" with meta info: "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."
Beyond that, in the console logs for that service account; there is zero activity.

And here is the error for either approach:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: { "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED", "domain": "googleapis.com", "errorInfoMetadata": { "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport", "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com" }, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https:\/\/developers.google.com\/identity\/sign-in\/web\/devconsole-project.", "code": 16, "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport", "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com" } } ] } thrown in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ga4-chart/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php on line 267
```

**What am I doing wrong? Beyond puzzled...**

Here is the complete code for reference below:

```
<?php

// Make sure we're running in a WordPress environment.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

// Load the Google API client library.
include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;


/**
 * Shortcode function that displays the chart.
 *
 * @param array $atts An array of shortcode attributes.
 * @return string The shortcode output.
 */
function ga4_chart_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Extract the shortcode attributes.
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'property_id' => '',
            'page_path' => '',
        ],
        $atts,
        'ga4_chart'
    );

    
    // Set the application credentials
    $json_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'client_secrets.json';
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $json_path); 

    // Initialize the Google Analytics client.
    $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

    // Get the property ID and page path from the shortcode attributes.
    $property_id = $atts['property_id'];
    $page_path = $atts['page_path'];

    // Set the date range for the last 90 days.
    $start_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-90 days' ) );
    $end_date = date( 'Y-m-d' );
    $date_range = new DateRange( ['start_date' => $start_date, 'end_date' => $end_date] );
    $date_ranges = [$date_range];


    // Set the dimensions and metrics for the request.
    $dimensions = [new Dimension( ['name' => 'pagePath' ] )];
    $metrics = [
        new Metric( ['expression' => 'entrances' ] ),
        new Metric( ['expression' => 'pageviews' ] ),
        new Metric( ['expression' => 'users' ] ),
        new Metric( ['expression' => 'newUsers' ] ),
    ];

    // Set the filters for the request.
    $filters = "pagePath == $page_path";

    // Make the request to the Google Analytics API.
    $response = $client->runReport(
        [
            'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
            'dateRanges' => $date_ranges,
            'dimensions' => $dimensions,
            'metrics' => $metrics,
            'filters' => $filters,
        ]
    );

    
    // Initialize the chart data.
    $data = [
        [ 'Metric', 'Value' ]
    ];

    // Add the data for each metric to the chart data.
    foreach ( $response->getData()->getRows() as $row ) {
        $metric_name = $row->getDimensions()[0];
        $metric_value = $row->getMetrics()[0]->getValues()[0];
        $data[] = [ $metric_name, (int) $metric_value ];
    }

    // Load the Google Charts library.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-charts', 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js', [], null, true );

    // Add a script to draw the chart.
    $chart_id = uniqid();
    $chart_data = json_encode( $data );
    $script = "
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($chart_data);
            var options = {
                title: 'Page Performance',
                hAxis: {title: 'Metric',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
                vAxis: {minValue: 0}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('$chart_id'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    ";
    wp_add_inline_script( 'google-charts', $script );

    // Return the chart HTML.
    return '<div id="' . $chart_id . '" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>';

    
}

// Register the shortcode.
add_shortcode( 'ga4_chart', 'ga4_chart_shortcode' );
```

Doing a var_dump of `$client`, they both produce the same result. So I feel this should be working? Maybe someone else has had a similiar problem starting out? Maybe I missed a setting in the console? Here is the output oif `$client` (Sensitive Info Redacted):

> object(Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient)#1126 (7) { ["transport":"Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient":private]=> object(Google\ApiCore\Transport\RestTransport)#1180 (4) { ["requestBuilder":"Google\ApiCore\Transport\RestTransport":private]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RequestBuilder)#1164 (2) { ["baseUri":"Google\ApiCore\RequestBuilder":private]=> string(32) "analyticsdata.googleapis.com:443" ["restConfig":"Google\ApiCore\RequestBuilder":private]=> array(1) { ["interfaces"]=> array(1) { ["google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData"]=> array(7) { ["BatchRunPivotReports"]=> array(4) { ["method"]=> string(4) "post" ["uriTemplate"]=> string(52) "/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:batchRunPivotReports" ["body"]=> string(1) "*" ["placeholders"]=> array(1) { ["property"]=> array(1) { ["getters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "getProperty" } } } } ["BatchRunReports"]=> array(4) { ["method"]=> string(4) "post" ["uriTemplate"]=> string(47) "/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:batchRunReports" ["body"]=> string(1) "*" ["placeholders"]=> array(1) { ["property"]=> array(1) { ["getters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "getProperty" } } } } ["CheckCompatibility"]=> array(4) { ["method"]=> string(4) "post" ["uriTemplate"]=> string(50) "/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:checkCompatibility" ["body"]=> string(1) "*" ["placeholders"]=> array(1) { ["property"]=> array(1) { ["getters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "getProperty" } } } } ["GetMetadata"]=> array(3) { ["method"]=> string(3) "get" ["uriTemplate"]=> string(36) "/v1beta/{name=properties/*/metadata}" ["placeholders"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> array(1) { ["getters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "getName" } } } } ["RunPivotReport"]=> array(4) { ["method"]=> string(4) "post" ["uriTemplate"]=> string(46) "/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:runPivotReport" ["body"]=> string(1) "*" ["placeholders"]=> array(1) { ["property"]=> array(1) { ["getters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "getProperty" } } } } ["RunRealtimeReport"]=> array(4) { ["method"]=> string(4) "post" ["uriTemplate"]=> string(49) "/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:runRealtimeReport" ["body"]=> string(1) "*" ["placeholders"]=> array(1) { ["property"]=> array(1) { ["getters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "getProperty" } } } } ["RunReport"]=> array(4) { ["method"]=> string(4) "post" ["uriTemplate"]=> string(41) "/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:runReport" ["body"]=> string(1) "*" ["placeholders"]=> array(1) { ["property"]=> array(1) { ["getters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "getProperty" } } } } } } } } ["httpHandler":"Google\ApiCore\Transport\RestTransport":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle7HttpHandler)#1179 (1) { ["client":"Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Client)#1178 (1) { ["config":"GuzzleHttp\Client":private]=> array(8) { ["handler"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack)#1166 (3) { ["handler":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> object(Closure)#1173 (2) { ["static"]=> array(2) { ["default"]=> object(Closure)#1171 (2) { ["static"]=> array(2) { ["default"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler)#1167 (6) { ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#1168 (2) { ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> array(0) { } ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> int(50) } ["selectTimeout":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> int(1) ["active":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> int(0) ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } ["delays":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } ["options":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } } ["sync"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler)#1169 (1) { ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#1170 (2) { ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> array(0) { } ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> int(3) } } } ["parameter"]=> array(2) { ["$request"]=> string(10) "" ["$options"]=> string(10) "" } } ["streaming"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler)#1172 (1) { ["lastHeaders":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler":private]=> array(0) { } } } ["parameter"]=> array(2) { ["$request"]=> string(10) "" ["$options"]=> string(10) "" } } ["stack":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1174 (2) { ["static"]=> array(1) { ["bodySummarizer"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\BodySummarizer)#1165 (1) { ["truncateAt":"GuzzleHttp\BodySummarizer":private]=> int(240) } } ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(11) "http_errors" } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1175 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(15) "allow_redirects" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1176 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(7) "cookies" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1177 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(12) "prepare_body" } } ["cached":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> NULL } ["allow_redirects"]=> array(5) { ["max"]=> int(5) ["protocols"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "http" [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(5) "https" } ["strict"]=> bool(false) ["referer"]=> bool(false) ["track_redirects"]=> bool(false) } ["http_errors"]=> bool(true) ["decode_content"]=> bool(true) ["verify"]=> bool(true) ["cookies"]=> bool(false) ["idn_conversion"]=> bool(false) ["headers"]=> array(1) { ["User-Agent"]=> string(12) "GuzzleHttp/7" } } } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(5) "async" } ["transportName":"Google\ApiCore\Transport\RestTransport":private]=> string(4) "REST" ["clientCertSource":"Google\ApiCore\Transport\RestTransport":private]=> NULL } ["credentialsWrapper":"Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient":private]=> object(Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper)#1163 (2) { ["credentialsFetcher":"Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper":private]=> object(Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenCache)#1162 (5) { ["fetcher":"Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenCache":private]=> object(Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials)#1158 (6) { ["auth":protected]=> object(Google\Auth\OAuth2)#1159 (26) { ["authorizationUri":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["tokenCredentialUri":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri)#1160 (8) { ["scheme":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(5) "https" ["userInfo":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["host":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(21) "oauth2.googleapis.com" ["port":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> NULL ["path":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(6) "/token" ["query":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["fragment":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["composedComponents":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> NULL } ["redirectUri":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["clientId":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["clientSecret":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["username":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["password":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["scope":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["state":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["code":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["issuer":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> string(84) "serviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" ["audience":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> string(35) "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" ["sub":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["expiry":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> int(3600) ["signingKey":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> string(1704) "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- -----END PRIVATE KEY----- " ["signingKeyId":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["signingAlgorithm":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> string(5) "RS256" ["refreshToken":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["accessToken":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["idToken":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["expiresIn":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["expiresAt":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["issuedAt":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["grantType":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> NULL ["extensionParams":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> array(0) { } ["additionalClaims":"Google\Auth\OAuth2":private]=> array(0) { } } ["quotaProject":protected]=> NULL ["projectId":protected]=> string(30) "protectedID" ["lastReceivedJwtAccessToken":"Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials":private]=> NULL ["useJwtAccessWithScope":"Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials":private]=> bool(true) ["jwtAccessCredentials":"Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials":private]=> NULL } ["eagerRefreshThresholdSeconds":"Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenCache":private]=> int(10) ["maxKeyLength":"Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenCache":private]=> int(64) ["cacheConfig":"Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenCache":private]=> array(2) { ["lifetime"]=> int(1500) ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" } ["cache":"Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenCache":private]=> object(Google\Auth\Cache\MemoryCacheItemPool)#1161 (2) { ["items":"Google\Auth\Cache\MemoryCacheItemPool":private]=> NULL ["deferredItems":"Google\Auth\Cache\MemoryCacheItemPool":private]=> NULL } } ["authHttpHandler":"Google\ApiCore\CredentialsWrapper":private]=> object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle7HttpHandler)#1157 (1) { ["client":"Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Client)#1156 (1) { ["config":"GuzzleHttp\Client":private]=> array(8) { ["handler"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack)#1144 (3) { ["handler":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> object(Closure)#1151 (2) { ["static"]=> array(2) { ["default"]=> object(Closure)#1149 (2) { ["static"]=> array(2) { ["default"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler)#1145 (6) { ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#1146 (2) { ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> array(0) { } ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> int(50) } ["selectTimeout":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> int(1) ["active":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> int(0) ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } ["delays":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } ["options":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } } ["sync"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler)#1147 (1) { ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#1148 (2) { ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> array(0) { } ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> int(3) } } } ["parameter"]=> array(2) { ["$request"]=> string(10) "" ["$options"]=> string(10) "" } } ["streaming"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler)#1150 (1) { ["lastHeaders":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler":private]=> array(0) { } } } ["parameter"]=> array(2) { ["$request"]=> string(10) "" ["$options"]=> string(10) "" } } ["stack":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1152 (2) { ["static"]=> array(1) { ["bodySummarizer"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\BodySummarizer)#1143 (1) { ["truncateAt":"GuzzleHttp\BodySummarizer":private]=> int(240) } } ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(11) "http_errors" } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1153 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(15) "allow_redirects" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1154 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(7) "cookies" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#1155 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(12) "prepare_body" } } ["cached":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> NULL } ["allow_redirects"]=> array(5) { ["max"]=> int(5) ["protocols"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "http" [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(5) "https" } ["strict"]=> bool(false) ["referer"]=> bool(false) ["track_redirects"]=> bool(false) } ["http_errors"]=> bool(true) ["decode_content"]=> bool(true) ["verify"]=> bool(true) ["cookies"]=> bool(false) ["idn_conversion"]=> bool(false) ["headers"]=> array(1) { ["User-Agent"]=> string(12) "GuzzleHttp/7" } } } } } ["retrySettings":"Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient":private]=> array(7) { ["BatchRunPivotReports"]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings)#1137 (10) { ["retriesEnabled":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> bool(false) ["retryableCodes":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> array(0) { } ["initialRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["retryDelayMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(0) ["maxRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["initialRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["rpcTimeoutMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(1) ["maxRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["totalTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["noRetriesRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) } ["BatchRunReports"]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings)#1138 (10) { ["retriesEnabled":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> bool(false) ["retryableCodes":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> array(0) { } ["initialRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["retryDelayMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(0) ["maxRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["initialRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["rpcTimeoutMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(1) ["maxRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["totalTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["noRetriesRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) } ["CheckCompatibility"]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings)#1136 (10) { ["retriesEnabled":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> bool(false) ["retryableCodes":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> array(0) { } ["initialRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["retryDelayMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(0) ["maxRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["initialRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["rpcTimeoutMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(1) ["maxRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["totalTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["noRetriesRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) } ["GetMetadata"]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings)#1139 (10) { ["retriesEnabled":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> bool(false) ["retryableCodes":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> array(0) { } ["initialRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["retryDelayMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(0) ["maxRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["initialRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["rpcTimeoutMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(1) ["maxRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["totalTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["noRetriesRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) } ["RunPivotReport"]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings)#1140 (10) { ["retriesEnabled":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> bool(false) ["retryableCodes":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> array(0) { } ["initialRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["retryDelayMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(0) ["maxRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["initialRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["rpcTimeoutMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(1) ["maxRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["totalTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["noRetriesRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) } ["RunRealtimeReport"]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings)#1141 (10) { ["retriesEnabled":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> bool(false) ["retryableCodes":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> array(0) { } ["initialRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["retryDelayMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(0) ["maxRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["initialRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["rpcTimeoutMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(1) ["maxRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["totalTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["noRetriesRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) } ["RunReport"]=> object(Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings)#1142 (10) { ["retriesEnabled":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> bool(false) ["retryableCodes":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> array(0) { } ["initialRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["retryDelayMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(0) ["maxRetryDelayMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(0) ["initialRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["rpcTimeoutMultiplier":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> float(1) ["maxRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["totalTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) ["noRetriesRpcTimeoutMillis":"Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings":private]=> int(60000) } } ["serviceName":"Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient":private]=> string(46) "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData" ["agentHeader":"Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient":private]=> array(1) { ["x-goog-api-client"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(60) "gl-php/8.1.13 gapic/0.9.2 gax/1.18.1 grpc/ rest/1.18.1 pb/+n" } } ["descriptors":"Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient":private]=> array(0) { } ["transportCallMethods":"Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient":private]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(14) "startUnaryCall" [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)=> string(22) "startBidiStreamingCall" [2]=> string(24) "startClientStreamingCall" [3]=> string(24) "startServerStreamingCall" } }

Comment: What is your question exactly?   Verification on two different ways to create the client?

Comment: Which way is correct and what am I missing? The var_dump of $client in both cases comes out identical with the key information intact. However, I'm receiving an error of "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED" with meta info: "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there are three ways to load the client credentials in to the client object.

## env var

```
// Set the application credentials
$json_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'client_secrets.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $json_path); 

// Initialize the Google Analytics client.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
```

## key file path

```
// Authenticate using a keyfile path
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
    'keyFilePath' => 'path/to/keyfile.json'
]);
```

## key file data

```
// Authenticate using keyfile data
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/keyfile.json'), true)
]);
```

They should be interchangeable.

Comment: env var (already using) key file data (already using) key file path (tried, same error). All of these produce "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED" with meta info: "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.". I'm stumped because they all seem to be working correctly but, Google gives me the auth error... I've done this as well with the template project. Same error.

Comment: can you open your key file and verify the type is service account?  also did you grant the service account access to the google analytics account you are trying to access.?

Comment: first line of json = "type": "service_account" and yes, I think? I have the service account attached to the properties via Property access management. Do I need to grant it access to the account as a whole too somehow?

Comment: take the service account email address and add it as a user in the admin section of your google analytics account

Comment: Yes.. it is attached to both the Account Access Management and Property Access Management. Is there another place besides this?